# SUID exploit and patch

Tags: access-control, unix, system-compromise

I am working on a SUID root binary "app" that runs a `system("ls -la /dir")` command. I managed to exploit it by writing a malicious replacement `ls` that starts a shell, and changed my user's `$PATH` such that the malicious `ls` executes instead of the one in `/bin`.

I noticed that executing it as user returns a root shell while executing it with `sudo "./example"` uses root's path and simply lists the files in dir. As far as I know, setuid inherits owner's (in this case root) privileges to user and sudo executes as root.

What are such vulnerabilities called?
How would an app developer patch it?
Is there any way I can force users to use `sudo ./app` to execute a program?

**the binary is a statically linked executable

Comment: Did you modify the code of ls? So essentially you are replacing a benign binary used by the app and getting a root shell as a result?

Comment: @Limit: Running the setuid executable with a different `PATH`.

Comment: yes, that's what i did.

Comment: `sudo` itself executes as root, and can execute the given command as any user depending on configuration _usually_ root, but first it sanitizes the environment including PATH to prevent exactly the attack you are attempting. If app does things that require privilege and you make it _not_ suid-root (and not setcap, if applicable) then non-root users who run it without `sudo` will presumably have it fail harmlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricking a program with more privileges to do something that the owner of the program didn't intend is called [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation).

When a privileged program reads data from the outside, it should verify that this data is harmless. This is called [data sanitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_sanitization). For example, a setuid program that executes an external program should verify that the program it's executing is the intended one. In this case the program depends both on the comamnd string `ls -la /dir` and on the value of the `PATH` environment variable¹. The only safe values for `PATH` are those such that the first entry for `ls` and any other command that the program might execute is the intended one; in practice that means completely ignoring the external information (the value of `PATH` in the environment) and setting `PATH` to a known safe value.

Sudo removes most environment variables, including `PATH` which it sets to a safe default. This makes it easier to write safe privileged components by using sudo rather than a custom setuid program for privilege elevation. A program run through `sudo` starts up with a safe value for `PATH`. You can still get things wrong, of course. For example allowing a user to run `sudo ./example` allows them to run whatever they want since they can create an executable called `example` in the directory of their choice.

¹  <sub>And `LD_xxx` variables used by the dynamic linker, but the dynamic linker of the setuid program wipes those when it sees that the program it's linking is setuid.</sub>

Comment: Would setting up a sudo entry, without need to type the password, to allow your users to run the 'example' binary with its owner's ID be a safe solution ?

Comment: @Gian Safe for what? It allows the user to run `example` as root. What do you mean by “with its owner's ID”?

Comment: i just got this. By owner i mean the binary owner. Anyway Thanks